# ERROR Adding Astoriacore custom class module

Tags: azerothcore

can anyone help with this? this is my first time adding custom modules/scripts. please see images

I checked the directory of the lua script and I have the spell.data file there

I also have added the classless table in my database....
not sure why it isnt working??

Load Channels...

> > Loaded 0 channels for Alliance
> > Loaded 0 channels for Horde
> > lua_scripts/AIO_Server/AIO.lua:395: lua_scripts\ClassLess\data\spells.data: No such file or directory
> > [Eluna]: Executed 7 Lua scripts in 9 ms
> > WORLD: World initialized in 0 minutes 10 seconds
> > AC>worldserver process priority class set to -15
> > Max allowed socket connections 1024
> > Starting up Auction House Listing thread...
> > AzerothCore rev. b8b5f68f98ff 2021-04-19 06:49:48 +0000 (master branch) (Unix, Release) (worldserver-daemon) ready...

[ubuntu terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGWIZ.png)

[dbeaver sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKWYj.png)

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ma8t.png)

Answer (score 1):

As for the Lua error my guess is that the scripts you are supplying are using Windows style paths (with `\` instead of `/`). Try replacing the backslashes with forward slashes.

As for the database error, in DBeaver you are showing a separate database called `characters` but acore is looking for the table in the database called `acore_characters`, so try to make the table there.